# Overlap a transparent foreground of a Relative layout to make text views color gray transparent inside Relative layout

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I tried following:

Created a frame layout containing that relative layout and made foreground /background color transparent. But I got transparent layout above my Relative Layout But Cannot see the textviews of Relatives layout which was initially of dark black color.

Also tried dynamically by creating a drawable with transparent color setting it to foreground of frame layout containing that relative layout.
getting still the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated ?

Comment: Post xml layout file.

Comment: Hi, solved it by setting correct Alpha value in view.setAlpha().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by just setting correct Alpha.

```
view.setAlpha(x);
```

I had initially set up the value of x as 90 which has no effect on the view.
After setting up the value of x as 0.9f (float/double), it worked.